# How did the word "busybody" end up meaning so different from what it appears on its face to imply?

Tags: meaning, etymology, nouns, confusables

When I learned the word *busybody* the first time, I was in 5th grade. It appeared in a story I had to learn for class. I figured it meant someone who was very busy, and didn't bother to look it up. When the teacher asked us if I had looked it up as I was supposed to as part of my homework, I lied and said I did. When I told her I found the meaning "in a dictionary" she asked me to bring her the dictionary. Needless to say, I was a very embarrassed 5th grader caught in a bad lie.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Etymonline has [this](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=busy&searchmode=none):

> **busy** O.E. *bisig* "careful, anxious, busy, occupied," [...]. In M.E., sometimes with a sense of "prying, meddlesome," preserved in **busybody**.

So, the word *busybody* didn't "end up meaning" what it does; much rather, it had that meaning all along. It's *busy* that used to have an additional meaning it no longer has in contemporary English. (If you read that Etymonline entry, you'll notice that that's not the only meaning that *busy* used to have but no longer does except in the idiom *get busy*: "The word was a euphemism for 'sexually active' in 17c.".)

Answer (score -4):

I think it has something to do with the origins of the idiom. It did not originate as a word, but as an idiom. It must have been a euphemistic way to refer to busybodies, and people in the same social circle must be using the word to describe their friend in a public setting.

Of course, all this is my guess. Please correct me if I am wrong.